# Convert Math equation into string

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, nsstring

![HERE is what my log is showing][1]I am working on a calculator and I have a function that takes in user input and then will display the answer just lie a normal calculator. I want to save any user input into a string such as "2+2=4" into an array which can then be viewed later.

Is there any way to convert the double values into strings? and also how would i save this string in the array.

Below is some code which i have tried, but have had no luck.
The below method is used to call the users input

```
  NSString *leftString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d + %d", left, right]; 
    _array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: leftString, nil];
```

Comment: User input is automatically a string... I'm not understanding your issue here...

Comment: But your string with format expression is wrong. I'll write an answer to address that.

Comment: And also, what does that "foo", "bar", "baz" array have to do with anything? When you say you want to save the string into an array, what are the exact results you're looking for?

Comment: foo, bar and baz wa me just tresting to see if i could add into the array. I want to just add the full string equation into the array

Comment: But what results do you want? For example array = [("2+2=4")] or array = [("2"), ("+"), ("2"), ("="), ("4")] or array = [("2"),("2"), ("4")] etc...

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
NSString *leftString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", left "+" right];
```

should be like this:

```
NSString *leftString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f + %f", left, right];
```

where the plus sign is within the expression and the `%f` indicates `left` and `right` are doubles.

Comment: how would i add leftstring into my array? _array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:leftstring,nil]; ?

Comment: Right. `%d` is for ints.

Comment: @John Like I said, it depends on what sort of results you want, ex  `array = [("2+2=4")]` or `array = [("2"), ("+"), ("2"), ("="), ("4")]` or `array = [("2"),("2"), ("4")]` etc...

Comment: im getting 0.0000 in both my left and right. Its not saving the user input. IS there a reason why its doing that? and i want to save it as "2+2=4"

Comment: @John What is `[self setOperand]` supposed to return? Perhaps you should also post that method.

Comment: [self setOperand] is what the user has typed in. I added the method to the question

Comment: @John OK, so you're putting user input into an array and then pulling off the last object to use it as a double. Are you sure you're inputting the user entries into the array correctly?

Comment: Yes the user input is being inputted correctly, i have updated my method and now the strings appear but they are not entirely correct. Please check my second edit.

Comment: @John There's definitely something wrong with the way you're adding your user input to your self.operand array. I'd recommend posting the code where you add your user input to the array.

Comment: HI, please check my updated question. I have added the relevant parts of the code in

Comment: Also i have put up a screenshot of what i am receiving in my log

Comment: @John There's still more relevant code missing... Basically anywhere you set a value by calling a method that you haven't posted makes that line of code indecipherable. I'd honestly recommend just posting your entire project online and posting a link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to have an array like so: [left, operation symbol, right] then you do the following:

```
NSString *leftString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", left];
NSString *rightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", right];
NSString *operationString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", operation];
```

Then do the following to add all of them into an array:

```
_array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: leftString, operation, rightString, nil];
```